# Error creating and seeding database using Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I run this code with IIS it is working, but if I am using Docker I get the below error. Could anybody help me solve this issue?

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    //Seed database
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        try
        {
            var databaseInitializer = services.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseInitializer>();
            databaseInitializer.SeedAsync().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogCritical(LoggingEvents.INIT_DATABASE, ex, LoggingEvents.INIT_DATABASE.Name);

            throw new Exception(LoggingEvents.INIT_DATABASE.Name, ex);
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

```
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
 Error whilst creating and seeding database
      System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at IdentityDAL.DatabaseInitializer.SeedAsync() in C:\Users\Host\source\repos\GTK\IdentityDAL\DatabaseInitializer.cs:line 43
      ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
```

Comment: looks like its unable to see the sql server.

Comment: Which version of docker image you are using? Can you share the related connection string? Perhaps you are using `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb` connection string inside the Docker container, since the LocalDB is installed on my computer and not inside the container, it will show the database connection error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use link bellow for solve your problem:

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)